# How can I easily model an extruded organic shape?

Tags: modeling, workflow

I am currently seeking help from the blender community to model this:

[image]

I've tried almost every tool (including subsurf) but it doesn't look like it

Can anyone show the steps on how to model that shape? I could be grateful if someone helped me

By the way,the top and "butt" (bottom left on the "sides" image) are supposed to be a little rounded and a little low-poly like (maybe both)

It also needs to be fully 3D,not 2d or flat

Comment: ...which kind of object should this represent, just to understand?

Comment: The body of a character i created

Comment: Is this just supposed to be a flat image, or some kind of boxy shape? I'd be happy to help, but I'm not 100% clear on what you're looking for.

Comment: It is supposed to be 3d @jemtan990

Comment: @Problematico Can you draw it in perspective? its really hard to tell what you want.

Comment: @GiantCowFilms the image is at perspective now

Comment: @Problematico Are you trying to create a character from ''Worms'' game ;) ?

Comment: @Gonzou No,i'm trying to make a shape that i can use for a character that i created (i'm serious,it's not from worms,It''s not a OC neither)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an easy way to do this. Go to User Preferences (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>-->*Add-ons*) and enable the ***Extra Objects*** add-on.
[image]

In *Object Mode* press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>-->*Mesh*-->*Pipe Joints*-->*Pipe Elbow* and play with the settings to get the desired parameters as pictured in .gif below.
[image]

Fill the opened tips of the pipe with <kbd>F</kbd> key, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to bevel them. Set the desired *Segments* amount. Now give the object the *Subsurf Modifier*, select some vertices, where the pipe is bent and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to sharpen it.
[image]

Comment: Hey bud,you almost had what i needed! sadly,i made a mistake,it is supposed to look like the image above,but because i said that the it had to be rounded on the bottom right it looked like a worm.Anyway,since your method seems useful,i will use it to make what i need

Answer (score 3):

You can easily do it with a curve. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> *> Curve > Circle*.

In *Edit Mode* do something like this:

[image]

Then:

[image]

Hope that helped you!

Answer (score 2):

To create a shape like this I first extruded (<kbd>E</kbd>) the top and one side of the default cube, then added some loop cuts with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.  Adding a subsurf modifier will smooth the boxy shape out.

[image]

You can play with the proximity cuts to adjust the smoothness of the subsurfing if you want more or less boxyness.